# jqvmap - applying color to multiple states/regions

Tags: jquery, jqvmap

With jquery and jqvmap, I'm setting multiple state colors in a US map. For instance, to color all the states that start with "A" red, this works:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {al: 'red'});
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {ak: 'red'});
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {az: 'red'});
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {ar: 'red'});
```

is there a way to make that shorter? I'd like to do this:

```
var astates = ["al", "ak", "az", "ar"];
for (var i = 0; i < astates.length; ++i) {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', { 'astates[i]' : 'red'}); 
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks

Comment: not sure if it was just a typo when you posted the question, but I don't think your astates variable should be in quotes.  But you are correct that it needs to be a string...so either escape those quotes or do the ugly old '''+astates[i]+''' 
Your loop looks like it should work otherwise.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510913/jqvmap-how-do-i-set-a-state-color-in-the-usa-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var fc = 'red'; // you'll need this if you'll want to change the whole group color someday
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {al: fc, ak: fc, az: fc, ar:fc});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
colorsST = {};
var astates = ["al", "ak", "az", "ar"];
for (var i = 0; i < astates.length; ++i) {
    colorST[i] = 'red';
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', colorST); 
}
```

Comment: By doing `colorST[i]` you are assigning not the states as the properties, but rather their index. This is what you would get: `0: 'red', 1: 'red'`, etc... So instead, you should do `colorST[astates[i]] = 'red'`. This will assign the state names as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this function as following:

```
let colors =  < any > {};

let colors = {
    "zz": "#006491",
    "us": "#1a769f",
    "nl": "#bde6f9",
    "at": "#c0e8fa",
    "tr": "#c0e8fa",
    "ie": "#c0e9fb"
}

jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', colors);
```

And may you need different colors (I had needed :) ) for example according to some value you can calculate some start colors and calculate with min and max value

```
let myValuesMap: Map<string, number> = new Map(); //{"zz" => 3011, "us" => 2669, "at" => 260, "nl" => 172, "tr" => 148, "ie"=>101}
let max = 0, min = Number.MAX_VALUE, startColor = [200, 238, 255], endColor = [0, 100, 145], colors = <any>{}, hex;

myValuesMap.forEach((value: number, key: string) => {
  if (value > max) { max = value }
  if (value < min) { min = value }
});

myValuesMap.forEach((value: number, key: string) => {
  if (value > 0) {
    colors[key] = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      hex = Math.round(startColor[i] + (endColor[i] - startColor[i]) * (value == max ? 1 : (value / (max - min)))).toString(16);
      if (hex.length == 1) { hex = '0' + hex; }
      colors[key] += (hex.length == 1 ? '0' : '') + hex;
    }
  }
});

jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', colors);
```